# Problem with displaying rows of 3 in php

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I have a script that is suppose to display my code into rows of 3, and create a new row. However, it is all displayed in one column. Here's the code.

```
while($mysql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
$prodlogo = $mysql2['logo'];
$prodid = $mysql2['id'];
$prodname = $mysql2['name'];

$x = 1;

if($x==1) {
    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "<td><img src=images/productpics/$prodlogo></br><a href=viewproduct.php?pid=$prodid>$prodname</a></td>";


$x++; 

if($x==3) {
    echo "</tr>";
    $x = 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the $x out of the loop,otherwise you are reset it to one in every loop

Answer (score 1):

each <td> will be a separate column. I would suggest you format it thus.

```
while($mysql2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    foreach($mysql2 as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['logo']."</td><td>$".row['id']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

also you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array you can access like $row['key']

Answer (score 0):

You may need to instantiate `$x = 1` outside of your while loop - you're resetting it to 1 each time you're running it.

Using modulo might be good too:

```
if (($x % 3) == 0) {
   echo "<tr>"
}

echo "<td><img src=images/productpics/$prodlogo></br><a href=viewproduct.php?pid=$prodid>$prodname</a></td>";

if (($x % 3) == 0) {
   echo "</tr>"
}
```

You wouldn't need to worry about resetting $x to 1...